# Bind Mosca listening IP address?

Tags: node.js, mqtt, mosca

Is there a way to listen for incoming network connection exclusively on a specific ip address/hostname? Preferably dynamically by passing the ip address/hostname in code as opposed to editing a config file.

Could find no reference to this in Mosca's documentation - http://www.mosca.io/docs/ which is why I'm posting.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in the docs [here](http://www.mosca.io/docs/lib/server.js.html#Server). You can pass in both a `host` and `port` as part of the options object when creating a new `mosca.Server` object.

```
var pubsubsettings = {
  //using ascoltatore
  type: 'mongo',        
  url: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/mqtt',
  pubsubCollection: 'ascoltatori',
  mongo: {}
};

var moscaSettings = {
  port: 1883,           //mosca (mqtt) port
  host: "127.0.0.1",
  backend: pubsubsettings   //pubsubsettings is the object we created above 

};

var server = new mosca.Server(moscaSettings);   //here we start mosca
server.on('ready', setup);  //on init it fires up setup()

// fired when the mqtt server is ready
function setup() {
  console.log('Mosca server is up and running')
}
```